# Need a way in Pandas to perform a robust standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, robust

I need pandas to calculate a robust standard deviation

I'm performing outlier analysis on electrical measurements in python today and refactoring the code in a pandas environment.  An issue that I have is in calculating standard deviation.  If the outliers are present in the population when calculating std, the resulting value is too large and is due to the presence of the outliers.  In my original python code, I've written robust mean an standard deviation functions to get back to a more normal population in order to calculate the outlier limits. Note, I also use this normalized population to calculate skewness and kurtosis because they are highly affected by outliers.

What I've been looking at is normalizing the population by using a 95% quantile of the data set and calculating from there for outlier limits. Does anyone know if anyone else in the pandas community has worked on robust statistics functions.  If not, I'll forge ahead.

df["#18.1355"].describe()
count    2694.000000
mean        1.808318
std         6.426645
min         0.920686
25%         1.357991
50%         1.521781
75%         1.801604
max       334.196900
Name: #18.1355, dtype: float64

Note that the far outlier in the max value.

The standard deviation of a normalized population for the above measurement is ~0.8

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not specific to pandas, but have you considered using the biweight midvariance? (see for an example of implementation http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.stats.biweight_midvariance.html)